# How can define the model in node js like object

Tags: javascript, node.js

My model is as below

```
var Employee = function (emp) {
   (this.firstname = emp.firstName),
    (this.middlename = emp.middleName),
    (this.lastname = emp.lastName),
    (this.mobile_phone = emp.mobilePhone),
    (this.home_phone = emp.homePhone),
    (this.work_phone = emp.workPhone),
    (this.email = emp.email),
    (this.personal_email = emp.personalEmail),
    (this.password = emp.password),
    (this.gender = emp.gender),
    (this.address1 = emp.address1),
    (this.address2 = emp.address2),
    (this.city = emp.city),
    (this.state = emp.state);
}
```

If I hit the update request in Node API then I get raw format data like below:

```
 {
    "firstName":"Shaunak",
    "middleName":"D",
    "lastName":"Patel",
    "email":"php.shaunak@spaculus.info",
    "workPhone":"121212121",
    "address":{
      "address1":"ewrewrwer",
      "address2":"werwe4343434rwer"
     }
    }
```

So how can define this raw format in my constructor model?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose to use the comma operator instead of just using separate lines?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: The raw data does not carry/provide all of the data which gets assigned from within the constructor function e.g. `mobilePhone`, `gender`, `city` ... What are the instance' default values in any of these cases?

Comment: @MohammadMalek ... are there any questions regarding the beneath approach?

Answer (score 0):

The OP might have a look into the [*object destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) part of *Destructuring assignments* as well as into [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

From the OP's questions one can not really tell what the (final) target structure is supposed to look like. But in case the OP's intention was to achieve both creating a flat property structure from the nested data entries that get passed into the constructor and also taking care of an `Employee` object's default values which are not provided by/from the raw data, one might use following parts of JavaScript's [*Destructuring assignment(s)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

- [Assigning to new variables names and providing default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values)
- [Setting a function parameter's default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#setting_a_function_parameters_default_value)
- [Rest in Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_in_object_destructuring)

```js
function Employee({
  gender = null,
  password = null,
  personalEmail: personal_email = null,
  mobilePhone: mobile_phone = null,
  workPhone: work_phone = null,
  homePhone: home_phone = null,
  address: { address1, address2 },
  city = null,
  state = null,
  ...baseConfig
}) {
  Object.assign(this, baseConfig, {
    gender,
    password,
    personal_email,
    mobile_phone,
    work_phone,
    home_phone,
    address1,
    address2,
    city,
    state
  });
}

const rawData = {
  "firstName":" Shaunak",
  "middleName": "D",
  "lastName": "Patel",
  "email": "php.shaunak@spaculus.info",
  "workPhone": "121212121",
  "address": {
    "address1": "ewrewrwer",
    "address2": "werwe4343434rwer",
  },
};

console.log(
  '... `Employee` instance properties ...',
  new Employee(rawData)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case the structure of the above logged `Employee` instance still does not meet the OP's requirements the OP needs to be more precise about the data passed to the constructor function and the expected structure as well as the default values of an `Employee` instance.